# Jeff Atwood appears as employee in API Results - even though he is not

Tags: bug, api, stack-exchange-team

I've been playing with the Stack Exchange API and developed a UserScript that adds icon next to users that are employees.

It appears as though the [Users method](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids#order=desc&sort=reputation&ids=1&filter=!G*ky*lRuf5kwiuOfK**wHecZHR&site=meta&run=true) of API is still reporting that [Jeff Atwood](https://stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) is an employee, yet his bio indicates that [he no longer works](https://blog.codinghorror.com/farewell-stack-exchange/) for the company.

> However, I no longer work at Stack Exchange, Inc.

Calling the Users method returns the following result. (*filtered unnecessary fields*)

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "account_id": 1,
      "is_employee": true,
      "reputation": 260720,
      "user_type": "moderator",
      "user_id": 1,
      "display_name": "Jeff Atwood"
    }
  ]
}
```

Should this be updated to reflect his currently employment status?

Comment: It's like a President of a country will always be called "President", even after retiring. It's just honor for the critical role the person had. Here on SE this honor also translates to actual power (diamond everywhere) but the  team trusts Jeff to not abuse that power, and I totally agree. :)

Comment: Is this really a dupe? We're talking about a specific API field here... Nobody's refuting his diamond! :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect this will end up with [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Since Jeff was one of the founders of the site (notice his `account_id`) they never revoked his diamond. I can't be sure, but it's not likely it will be revoked in the near future.

This has been [discussed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221124/269301).

While he's no longer an employee, he still has the privileges of one. Unlinking this to fix this specific bug would likely not be worth the trouble.