# Why does Jeff Atwood no longer have the diamond?

Tags: discussion, jeff-atwood

I noticed [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)'s accounts no longer use the diamond symbol.

Why does Jeff Atwood no longer have the diamond? Is this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

According to [jeff-atwood](/questions/tagged/jeff-atwood)'s tag excerpt and some posts on Meta (e.g. [Why does Jeff Atwood still have the diamond symbol?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221124/why-does-jeff-atwood-still-have-the-diamond-symbol) ), Jeff Atwood will always retain the honorary moderator status.

Did he only lose the diamond symbol itself or did he also lose the actual powers?

Comment: Then what about appending a ♦ symbol to his display name? That's ***honorable***.

Comment: @iDebug that would be way too confusing, IMO.

Comment: Its an end of an era :(

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Jeff's mod hammer, long wielded for glorious justice, has been officially retired.** (I'm told many professional sports teams do this to honor their former leaders' articles of clothing or designated integers.)

Jeff let us know that he's planning to take some time away from most internet interaction for a bit, and wanted to ensure that any of his accounts with special access wouldn't be a possible security exposure, given that he might not be actively monitoring them, etc.

Given that, plus the fact that it's been a little over half a decade since he had last worked here, we went ahead and changed his user_type from 'moderator' to 'founder_emeritus'. (Okay, so I made that up.)

Comment: Somewhat unrelated: Do you perchance know whether this also pertains to his blog?

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow unfortunately, I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: so will you return the diamond once he back?

Comment: *…a little over half a decade…* Do you mean six years? What happened to plain English?

Comment: @Mari-LouA six of one, a half dozen of the other?

Comment: *half a dozen years* would have been preferable, anyway interesting modern-day language development

Comment: @Mari-LouA You know, momentous occasions. "That's six small years for a man, one giant a-little-over-half-a-decade for Jeffkind."

Comment: If he does choose to return, is he still honorary moderator for life? In other words, can he simply request his global diamond back, or will he need to be elected as a moderator on a per-site basis?

Comment: How sad..........