# All of Jeff Atwood's Diamonds are gone except on Area51.Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, moderator-tools, jeff-atwood

I already acknowledge that Jeff Atwood's diamond was removed because he is on a break from the Internet and wanted his account un-modded for security reasons or so as described in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301841).

But it seems like one diamond was missed and that's the one on his [Area51.Meta.SE profile](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4). Also his account shows up in [moderator list](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).

Was the diamond kept on the site for reasons of honor or was it missed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Was the diamond kept on the site for reasons of honor or was it missed?

It was missed. Removed now.

Comment: Well, same for [jmac](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/83109/jmac), afaik he's no longer working for SE hence shouldn't have a diamond. (Also, his About Me [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/83109) should be cleared)