# Answer deleted by user with low rep

Tags: discussion

In the deleted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5481417/759019), it says Deleted by [Dori](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5481417/759019).

The user has 624 rep. If the user did flag for mod. attention, wouldn't it usually have the moderator's name there? How did this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10936/dori) [used to be a community team member](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/welcome-valued-associate-dori-smith/), and thus had a diamond on all sites.

She seems to have [left StackExchange in 2011](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/99341/4).

Comment: Ahhh. That explains it.

Comment: This is still confusing, I even [suggested a way around it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128261/152859) once. :)