# I received a private moderator message. May I share it?

Tags: support, moderators

I've received a private moderator message.
I'd like to share it.
As far as I can tell I am not in obligation to keep secret anything I'm told unless I've signed a Non Disclosure Agreement or similar. Stack Overflow's Terms Of Service have no such provisions.

Thus, may I share it freely?

[image]

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes, you can. The message is sent to you privately because issues like this are not other people's business. If you're okay with other people knowing about the details of why you were contacted and/or suspended, then that's fine. There is nothing prohibiting you from doing so. However, you should keep in mind that publicly sharing details also means that moderators can *also* talk about it publicly - you can't start a one-sided argument about a message. If you're not comfortable with moderators discussing the details of the contact in public, then you shouldn't publish it in public.

Comment: Can moderators send private moderator messages to users for non moderation purposes through SE? i.e., contacting them for participation or something else where there's nothing serious?

Answer (score 31):

You're welcome to share it if you want. One of the reasons we don't publicise them is to protect the privacy of those we are sending the message to. We don't want to broadcast what we think you've done wrong. You can discuss the message privately with the moderators by replying to the message or sending a message to the community team.

However, if you want to make it public there's nothing we can do (nor want to do) to prevent you doing just that, whether it's here on the Stack Exchange network or anywhere else on the internet.

The only people not allowed to publicly share mod messages are moderators.

Comment: We're not actually prohibited from sharing moderator messages. But in almost all cases it would not be a good idea to do it. (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293213/151385)

Comment: @MadScientist - technically true, but we're not allowed to divulge PII and more often than not that's included in the message.