# Am I allowed to create a Stack Overflow business card?

Tags: support, swag

Am I allowed to create a Stack Overflow business card for myself, using this template:

> [Stack Overflow Moderator Cards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94521/stack-overflow-moderator-cards/94528#94528)

Those are dedicated to moderators, but are we regular users allowed to create a same business card, only using different data on the front side of it?

Comment: Why would you need a Stack Overflow business card?  It would suggest an affiliation with the company that doesn't exist.

Comment: @psubsee2003 .. just asking  :)

Comment: I suppose you *could* always add a (shortened) link to your S.O profile, or add a line like "Top 1% on S.O"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**No**. From the **[Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance)**:

> - **Do** use the most current logo where applicable and permitted.
> - **Do** use the proper name for our company, product, or service (see    "Proper use of the Stack Exchange and Stack Exchange Name"
>   below).
> - ***Do not* use our logo unless you have been granted special permission    by Stack Exchange Inc.**
> - **Do not** use our name or logo in a way that might imply a false sense    of partnership or endorsement with your product.
> - **Do not** use any name or logo that is similar to or might be confused    with our name or logo.
> - **Do not** distort or alter our logo in any way.
> - **Do not** use our logo in a way that confuses our brand with another    brand.
> - **Do not** use any other artwork from our network without explicit    permission.

So unless given permission from a Stack Exchange employee, you are not allowed to use the Stack Overflow (or any Stack Exchange) logo in your business card.

If you still want to take your shot, ping them in chat, or wait until one of them answers this question definitively.