# Is it possible to get [at]stackoverflow[dot][com] email address

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderators, email

I know it kind of sounds absurd to ask. All the SO employees would be having this email address ending with stackoverflow dot com. I was just wondering if I can get this address. or does stackoverflow users get this address, may be once they cross  a particular reputation mark.

Comment: Simon is correct here; @stackoverflow.com addresses are not issued based on either reputation or moderator status.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I knew it wont be available to public, It was just wondering, but I hate the ppl answering without manners despite giving a disclaimer.

Comment: I disagree that anyone has been rude to you; the answers simply echo the truth: "no", with explanation. In all seriousness, I don't see anyone being rude to you here. Maybe you are misinterpreting the answers?

Comment: @MarcGravell, I am talking about this line:  
Server administrators probably have enough on their hands without dealing with your email problems and trying to setup a system for tons of people  AND
Stack Overflow is a Q and A site, not an email provider.

and did I not mention that in my question description

Comment: I don't think that is meant to be insulting - it is reality. Our mail address is maintained by our own admins, but this is simply **not their core duties**. Having to handle non-employee email accounts **would** be additional and unnecessary overhead. This is simply reality.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks Marc, I will take that, going to close this topic, Have a good day

Comment: That wasn't meant to be rude or insulting, it's just telling you how things are

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rep does not give you a stackoverflow.com email address.

I can imagine that moderators would get one, but don't know for certain.

---

Update:

As the comment by @Fezziwig (?) below and the answer by Simon Sheehan show, moderators do not get their own stackoverflow.com email address either.

Comment: Yup I can assume reps cant give you as you have loads of reps at SO and probably you haven't got one

Comment: There's a declined request to give mods official e-mails that I can't find right now, but no, they don't currently have them

Comment: Nope, mods don't get a SO email.  We aren't really employees, after all.

Comment: Perhaps @MichaelMrozek/Fezziwig (Mrozziwig?) was thinking of [Official e-mail account for moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40138/131713)? Or [Under what circumstances should moderators e-mail users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17173/131713)?

Answer (score 12):

Those emails are reserved for Stack Exchange employee. Moderators don't have them; they use their own personal ones, as you mostly see on moderator profiles. This will likely never change: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not an email provider.

Server administrators probably have enough on their hands without dealing with your email problems and trying to set up a system for tons of people.

Comment: Plus there may be collisions.

Comment: @BradGilbert what are collisions? As in names?

Comment: My name is Alfred Dmin. I want `admin@stackoverflow.com`

Comment: @TheP.G.RepMiningCo. Hahah, great reference then :p