# As central points of contact for a site, can moderators get a stack exchange email address?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, moderators, email

I have seen the [prior question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116405/154443) - but it didn't focus on what I would see as the value to each site, and by inference, the wider SE network:

As a representative of a site, possibly connecting with professional organisations and potential sponsors there would be value in having a consistent front, so that official communications could come from eg. a security.stackexchange email address.

It would also give some moderators the ability to entirely separate their work communications from their volunteer SE communications - this could be a good thing in some environments.

Comment: [Where do the team+sitename@stackexchange.com email addresses go?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141268) (and more importantly, its answer) seems relevant.

Comment: Yeah - that still seems to only be concerned with user-mod communications, not the wider outreach aspect.

Comment: Related: [Official e-mail account for moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40138/131713) and [Under what circumstances should moderators e-mail users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17173/131713)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any user can represent their site. You don't have to be a moderator. :)

But regardless of that, if you represent the site, you still have to be careful to avoid representing *Stack Exchange the Company*. That would be hard to do if you had a stackexchange.com email address.

If you want to separate your SE communications from other communications, use a different email address with Stack Exchange.

If you're worried about appearing professional, just make sure your email address isn't along the lines of "lovebug69@hotmail.com" when emailing a professional organization regarding your site. :) Beyond that, what you say and how you say it counts for a lot more than what email domain it came from.

Comment: Personally, I'm not worried about being professional :-) Maybe others do... But I just thought it was a marketing/outreach trick we were maybe missing.

Comment: @RoryAlsop In my experience (and I include myself in my pre-employment days in this assessment), lack of an SE.com email is not what stops folks from contacting organizations or doing various promotion-type stuff. :)